# How can I hide the repository actions heading menu that appears in the source control sidebar when my workspace has multiple repositories?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to hide the action buttons in the `Source control` explorer panel in Visual Studio Code since they take too much space and there is not enough space or the repository name. Is it possible to hide them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no. I looked through the settings and found `scm.alwaysShowActions` and `scm.showActionButton`, but neither of those seem to do what you're looking for.

If your workspace only has one repository, that action bar is hidden by default, which can be changed with `"scm.alwaysShowRepositories": true`. But unfortunately, that's like the opposite of what you're looking for.

If you want such a feature, you can [create a feature-request issue ticket on the VS Code GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.